# Is it possible to know how many items the user selected on ngx-awesome-uploader?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to know if it is possible to know how many items the user selected on ngx-awesome-uploader?

Answer (score 0):

Docs show it has output events that you can use to kep track of the internal workings

```
    /** Emitted when file upload via api success. Emitted for every file
    */ @Output() uploadSuccess = new  EventEmitter<FilePreviewModel>();
   /** Emitted when file upload via api fails. Emitted for every file */
    @Output() uploadFail = new  EventEmitter<HttpErrorResponse>();
   /** Emitted when file is removed via api successfully. Emitted for    every file *
    / @Output() removeSuccess = new     EventEmitter<FilePreviewModel>();
   /** Emitted on file validation fail */ 
    @Output() validationError =    new  EventEmitter<ValidationError>();
   /** Emitted when file is added and passed validations. Not uploaded    yet */ 
    @Output() fileAdded = new  EventEmitter<FilePreviewModel>();
   /** Emitted when file is removed from fileList */ 
    @Output()    fileRemoved = new  EventEmitter<FilePreviewModel>();
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-awesome-uploader

Comment: Hey, thanks, but in the Docs it is only about file by file. Every event about a file, I need something like a lenght or files. I would like to know how many were selected.